# How to Create a Hierarchy in SSAS when duplicate attributes exist at the Root

Tags: ssas, ssas-2008

I have a Dimensional table structure which resembles the following:

[image]

Ideally the hierarchial representation should be

CodeClassDesc --> CodeDesc

So A would be a Parent to A and B; B would be a Parent to A, B and C in my Analysis Server Cube. The problem is that because CodeClassDesc has multiple entries in the table it produces multiple duplicate Parents in my Cube with a single corresponding Child Element per Parent which is not what I'd consider a true Hierarchy. Or at least not what I am looking for the expected results.

I believe this is possible in SSAS without having to manipulate the data within the table via a VIEW but I don't know what I'm missing.

I've tried defining the CodeClassDesc and CodeDesc fields as a composite key but that doesn't work, yet I am almost certain there is a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

After attempting every conceivable permutation of methods to acquire resolution for this, I concluded that normalization of the required attribute was the only way to resolve the issue of having multiple entries of the Parent for every corresponding Child element.

So I created a VIEW of the table using a DISTINCT SELECT of only the CodeClass and CodeClassDesc fields in my DSV (DataSource View) in the Cube. Then I set the CodeClass field as a logical Primary Key and created a relationship between it and the CodeClass field of the main table.

I then used the CodeClassDesc field of the VIEW to create the top-level parent in my Dimension, which gave me only 1 distinct record for each value; and added the CodeDesc fields from the Table to create the Child Relationships. Works like a charm so I guess the answer would have to be that you cannot create a Parent Hierarchy consisting of a single Value per Parent if the source has multiple records.

Answer (score 0):

In the dimension structure, you should change the property KeyColumn of the attribute "CodeClassDesc" to a composite key containing both "CodeClassDesc" and "CodeDesc" then change the NameColumn property to show itself